# Where is "go" button in EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an editText and it shows a newline button instead of a go button. Why?

android:minLines="40"

Also, I'm showing the virtual keyboard using:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) TrackActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imm != null){
  imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a "Go" button, try this as your edittext element:

```
  <EditText
    android:text="EditText"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo" />
```

In other words set **imeOptions** to "**actionGo**".

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify what kind of an action keyboard you need. For your particular case, you will need to specify that you want a Go button.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widge/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionLabel

android:imeActionLabel="actionGo"

Answer (score 0):

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

Simple